# Modify SVG path on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I would like to change a svg path coordinates on hover, can I do that without using D3js ?

The SVG is a sort of graph I made on sketchapp, here's the code :

```
    <svg class="light-graph" viewBox="0 0 1440 269">
        <g id="ANALYTICS" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <g sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(0.000000, -331.000000)" id="header" fill="#3797D1" opacity="0.323868937">
                <g sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                    <g id="bg-graph" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                        <path d="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,569.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z"></path>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

What I would like to do is that the graph modifies with a smooth transition on hover. The graph would be placed on a header as a cover.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with SMIL e.g.

```
<path d="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,569.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z">
    <animate begin="mouseover" attributeName="d" to="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,69.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate begin="mouseout" attributeName="d" to="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,569.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
</path>
```

The begin attribute is the event you want to activate the animation on and the to is what the path will end up as.

fill="freeze" ensures that if you keep the mouse over the shape it stays in the animated position.

This is a complete standalone example that I tested in Firefox.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="light-graph" viewBox="0 0 1440 269">
    <g id="ANALYTICS" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(0.000000, -331.000000)" id="header" fill="#3797D1" opacity="0.323868937">
            <g>
                <g id="bg-graph">
                    <path d="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,569.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z">
                        <animate begin="mouseover" attributeName="d" to="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,69.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                        <animate begin="mouseout" attributeName="d" to="M1123.39844,467.39269 L869.398438,569.515104 L720,331.388951 L559.398438,369.409092 L379.398437,587.524641 L123.398438,427.439835 L0,600 L1440,600 L1123.39844,467.39269 Z" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Does not work here, nothing happen on hover, maybe you could show me a fiddle ? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: The values attribute is missing no?

Comment: Thanks Robert seems to be working here, but I have buttons that should be on top of my svg elements, but if I do a z-index -999 my svg is not "hoverable" anymore, how can I still hover my svg element and keepmy links clickable ?

Comment: If you're over the button you're not hovering on the chart. You can make SVG ignore the buttons but then you would not be able to click  on the buttons. This is another question though and you should ask it as such using the Ask Question button.

Comment: SMIL is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL It's better to use CSS "animation"

Comment: @dreamLo read on a little and it says Chrome suspended the deprecation. That was some years ago and they haven't tried to deprecate it since. SMIL is much much more powerful than CSS animation. You can chain animations, animate attributes rather than just CSS properties etc.