# highlight table when hover over svg map

Tags: javascript, html, css, xslt, svg

I have a "simple task" in mind, I have a original GML/XML created in `QGIS, I use xsl to transform it into html, so far OK. Now I have a table with the XML data and a SVG maps (found online), they are next to each other. What I want is that when you click on any area of the map it highlight the table row with the info.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/">


    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="eng" />
            <meta name="author" content="none"/>
            <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div>
                <header> 
                    <h1>Inhabitants</h1>
                </header>
            </div>

            <div id="container">

                <div id="map_area">
                    <div id="innermap_area">
                        <embed src="dr_map.svg" width="800px" height="600" type="image/svg+xml">    </embed>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="info">
                    <div id="innerinfo">
                        <table>
                        <tr bgcolor="#C3CEC6">
                          <th>Province name</th>
                          <th>Total inhabitants</th>          
                          <th>Female</th>
                          <th>Male</th>

                        </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//gml:featureMember">
                            <tr>
                              <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:TOPONIMIA"/></td>
                              <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:Casos"/></td>                  
                              <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:Mujeres"/></td>
                              <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:Hombres"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        <div><footer> 2017 </footer></div>

      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The svg file goes like this (this is cut because is too long, but I think it gives a good idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            .land
            {
                fill: #CCCCCC;
                fill-opacity: 1;
                stroke:white;
                stroke-opacity: 1;
                stroke-width:1;
                display:block;
            }
            .land:hover
            {
                fill: blue;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

        <dr_map projection="mercator" leftLongitude="-72.004173" topLatitude="19.932499" rightLongitude="-68.322347" bottomLatitude="17.470139"></dr_map>

    </defs>
    <g>
        <path id="DO-01" title="Distrito Nacional" class="land" d="M435.2,341.16l0.17,-2.24l2.37,-2.49l-0.13,-5.53l-1.32,-1.8l-5.01,-3.59l-1.32,-2.35l2.77,-1.52v-2.49l1.19,-2.76l1.72,-1.24l2.37,0.97l1.19,1.8l0.66,2.9l2.24,1.11l2.37,3.18l3.3,-1.38l7.65,-1.52l3.17,2.07v1.8l-1.85,3.46l0.3,2.37l0,0l-1.79,-0.25l-2.21,1.63l-4.24,1.57l-2.21,3.01l-2.45,1.25l-6.75,2.07H435.2z"/>
```

and now the GML/XML (again a piece of it, I eliminate the must of the coordinates)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="processing.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<FeatureCollection
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation=""
     xmlns="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
     xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <gml:name>province</gml:name>
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box>
      <gml:coord><gml:X>182215.7655999996</gml:X><gml:Y>1933511.9638</gml:Y></gml:coord>
      <gml:coord><gml:X>571429.3273</gml:X><gml:Y>2205216.25</gml:Y></gml:coord>
    </gml:Box>
  </gml:boundedBy>                                                                                                        
  <gml:featureMember>
    <rd id="DO-01">
      <geometryProperty><gml:MultiPolygon srsName="EPSG:32619"><gml:polygonMember><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>397122.65139999986,2050791.921 397142.0132,2050790.208699999 </gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></gml:polygonMember></gml:MultiPolygon></geometryProperty>
      <PROV>01</PROV>
      <TOPONIMIA>DISTRITO NACIONAL</TOPONIMIA>
      <Hombres>460903</Hombres>
      <Mujeres>504137</Mujeres>
      <Casos>965040</Casos>
    </rd>
</FeatureCollection>
```

Comment: So how do you relate an SVG element to a HTML table row? Does `path id="DO-01"` relate to `rd id="DO-01"`? And do you or at least can you recreate the SVG map to add links and/or Javascript so that the highlighting is implemented?

Comment: I want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332818/fill-svg-path-on-table-row-hover?rq=1   I try it but is not working properly in xslt structucture

Comment: Well, that example has the SVG inlined and not referenced by an `embed` element so that is much easier to achieve with CSS and Javascript. And it works onmouseover and not onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three code snippets, based on your snippets, the first is an XSLT stylesheet that takes your XML document as it primary input document and the SVG document as a parameter, it then transforms the XML and SVG into HTML with inline SVG, where the SVG path elements have `onmouseover`/`onmouseout` event handler attribute to highlight the background color of the corresponding table row with the data, it is assumed that the SVG path elements and the input XML `rd` elements have corresponding `id` attributes, based on these `id` attributes the element is highlighted (after the XSLT has prefixed the `id` for the SVG `path`, to avoid collisions in the single id namespace of the complete HTML+SVG document):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gml ogr">

    <xsl:param name="svg-uri" select="'test2017060301.svg'"/>
    <xsl:param name="svg-doc" select="document($svg-uri)"/>

    <xsl:param name="hover-color" select="'#CCC'"/>

    <xsl:param name="svg-width" select="800"/>
    <xsl:param name="svg-height" select="600"/>

    <xsl:param name="id-prefix" select="'path-'"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Example</title>
                <script>
                    function hover(element, backgroundColor) {
                      element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                    }
                    function unhover(element) {
                      element.style.backgroundColor = '';
                    }
                </script>
            </head>

            <body>

                <div>
                    <header> 
                        <h1>Inhabitants</h1>
                    </header>
                </div>

                <div id="container">

                    <div id="map_area">
                        <div id="innermap_area">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="$svg-doc/*" mode="svg">
                                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="$svg-width"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="height" select="$svg-width"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="info">
                        <div id="innerinfo">
                            <table>
                                <tr bgcolor="#C3CEC6">
                                    <th>Province name</th>
                                    <th>Total inhabitants</th>          
                                    <th>Female</th>
                                    <th>Male</th>

                                </tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="//gml:featureMember">
                                    <tr id="{ogr:rd/@id}">
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:TOPONIMIA"/></td>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:Casos"/></td>                  
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:Mujeres"/></td>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ogr:rd/ogr:Hombres"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div><footer> 2017 </footer></div>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="svg">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="svg"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="svg:svg" mode="svg">
        <xsl:param name="width" select="$svg-width"/>
        <xsl:param name="height" select="$svg-height"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                <xsl:value-of select="$width"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="height">
                <xsl:value-of select="$height"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="svg"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="svg:path" mode="svg">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($id-prefix, @id)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="onmouseover">hover(document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>'), '<xsl:value-of select="$hover-color"/>');</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="onmouseout">unhover(document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>'));</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test2017060301.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<FeatureCollection
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=""
    xmlns="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gml:name>province</gml:name>
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Box>
            <gml:coord><gml:X>182215.7655999996</gml:X><gml:Y>1933511.9638</gml:Y></gml:coord>
            <gml:coord><gml:X>571429.3273</gml:X><gml:Y>2205216.25</gml:Y></gml:coord>
        </gml:Box>
    </gml:boundedBy>                                                                                                        
    <gml:featureMember>
        <rd id="DO-01">
            <geometryProperty><gml:MultiPolygon srsName="EPSG:32619"><gml:polygonMember><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>397122.65139999986,2050791.921 397142.0132,2050790.208699999 </gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></gml:polygonMember></gml:MultiPolygon></geometryProperty>
            <PROV>01</PROV>
            <TOPONIMIA>DISTRITO NACIONAL</TOPONIMIA>
            <Hombres>460903</Hombres>
            <Mujeres>504137</Mujeres>
            <Casos>965040</Casos>
        </rd>
    </gml:featureMember>
</FeatureCollection>
```

And the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            .land
            {
            fill: #CCCCCC;
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke:white;
            stroke-opacity: 1;
            stroke-width:1;
            display:block;
            }
            .land:hover
            {
            fill: blue;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

        <dr_map projection="mercator" leftLongitude="-72.004173" topLatitude="19.932499" rightLongitude="-68.322347" bottomLatitude="17.470139"></dr_map>

    </defs>
    <g>
        <path id="DO-01" title="Distrito Nacional" class="land" d="M435.2,341.16l0.17,-2.24l2.37,-2.49l-0.13,-5.53l-1.32,-1.8l-5.01,-3.59l-1.32,-2.35l2.77,-1.52v-2.49l1.19,-2.76l1.72,-1.24l2.37,0.97l1.19,1.8l0.66,2.9l2.24,1.11l2.37,3.18l3.3,-1.38l7.65,-1.52l3.17,2.07v1.8l-1.85,3.46l0.3,2.37l0,0l-1.79,-0.25l-2.21,1.63l-4.24,1.57l-2.21,3.01l-2.45,1.25l-6.75,2.07H435.2z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Online sample is at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017060301.xml and works for that single line of data with IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! however, after copy the codes they dont appear to run correctly, only data with no format.

Comment: Does "after copy the codes they dont appear to run correctly, only data with no format" refer to the example I posted or to your attempt to adapt it? In any way, you will need to explain in more detail what that means, if you have adapted the posted solution and have run into problems then consider to edit your question and show us exactly what code you have now and explain precisely what does not work.

Comment: my bad, I adapt it to my original one and it wasnt running because of the name of the SVG was wrong!, stupid me and those errors of typo! thank you so much to take the time to help me :)